# Most useful reagent for gravimetric analysis of silver

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

My question reads as follows:

"What's the most useful reagent for the gravimetric analysis of silver from the options below:
A. Sodium nitrate
B. Barium carbonate
C. Potassium sulphate
D. Ammonium chloride"

I can rule out A and C as they do not form a silver precipitate with a solution containing silver. However, both B and D can form a silver precipitate so I am not sure which of them would be the most useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing something: before you even put the silver in, NH<sub>4</sub>Cl is soluble, while BaCO<sub>3</sub> has already precipitated (insoluble)!

This means that Cl- will precipitate more completely with NH<sub>4</sub>Cl.  Therefore, `D`.

Comment: Don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks anyway.